# entity framework adding record to join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Given 3 database tables: Businesses, Markets, BusinessesMarkets

I want to add a new business and I want the business to be in a particular market. How do I add to the join table in EntityFramework speak?

For example, the user wants to create a new business called ABC Co and add it to the Southern region market.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is making some assumptions about your domain model:

```
var southernRegion = db.Markets().Find(the_id);
var abcCo = new Business();

southernRegion.Businesses.Add(abcCo);

db.SaveChanges();
```

EF will handle the join table for you!

Comment: Very cool! one thing: southernGroup.Markets.Add(abcCo), I didn't have .Markets in intellisense. I had southernGroup.Businesses? The tooltip showed "Market.Businesses"

Comment: I just wanted to say, "thanks!" again. This was an epiphany for me. Can't believe this was 4 years ago! I was reminded of this because I was hopefully able to help someone today with this knowledge.